# Sql table arrangment

Tags: php, mysql

I have to post a product to mySql **where** each product can't be predicted how many colors it has; some product may have only one color or 10 colors.

For that reason, for this moment, I just create a bunch of **20 seperate colors table**, where all those tables are point to the main table named product.

[image]

My questions are:

First, how to link the "product table" to all colors "table"

Second, how to make a post to the "product table" and to the "colors table" at the same time. I mean, when I post one product into the "product table" for its title, description and its price, I am also able to post some different images of color to its each tables.

I do this with PHP form. Because I am very new in Mysql and PHP, so far I am only able to post some content to one table.

I hope anyone gets what I mean in the question above.

I am also looking for a different method If anyone have a smart way to do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, no, no, no, no!

In a running system the table design should not change. At least not much. Don't generate tables all the time.

A better table design would be using 2 tables for colors

```
colors table
------------
id
name


product_colors table
--------------------
product_id
color_id
```

Example data would be

```
products
id  title   description  ...
1   prod1   bla bla


colors
id   name
1    green
2    blue


product_colors
product_id  color_id
1           1
1           2
```

And then to get the colors for product `prod1` you can do

```
select c.name
from colors c
join product_colors pc on pc.color_id = c.id
join products p on pc.product_id = p.id
where p.title = 'prod1'
```

That design is flexible - you can have as many colors as you like for a product and it is very fast in quering.

Comment: I forgot to tell if each colors of the product will have four main images and four thumnail images (which will be a slideshow). When you click to the color red, for instance, the slideshow will change for the prodcut of colored red with its four main images and four thunail images. I am really confused.

Comment: Then use an additional table called `color_images`. It contains the columns `color_id` and `image`. In that you can add the images of the colors.

Comment: Yes, I got the idea with your answer above. I just need to create some coloms for main images and thumnail images in the table of colors. Thank you so much. You are briliant. :)